# Reported speech: "would do something", or "would have done something"

Tags: indirect-speech, would

What would the following be in reported speech?

Q "If I had any money I'd buy you a drink" she said.

(a) She told me she would buy me a drink if she had any/some money

or

(b) She told me she would have bought me a drink if she had had any/some money

Presumably the former (a) is correct. Otherwise for (b), the Question would presumably have been: "If I had had any money I would have bought you a drink" she said

Comment: No; (b) is the corresponding sentence in reported speech. (a) shows a 'future conditional  promise in the past' ('If I [see you in town next week, and I] have any money, I'll buy you a drink' she said). //// Note that (a) 'If I had any money I'd buy you a drink' may be (near-)paraphrased 'If I were flush at the moment I'd buy you a drink'.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you Edwin. I had a feeling (a) might be wrong, but couldn't work out why .

Comment: 'If she had had' can always look a bit dubious, even when it's correct. '... if she'd had ...', in speech, is nowhere near as awkward.

Comment: I can't decide what the Question would be for (a) to be the reported speech answer?

Comment: Think of the extended sentence 'She told me she would buy me a drink if she had some money the next time we met.' "I'll buy you a drink next time we meet, if I have any money" she said. Then delete to [... "I may see you next time I'm passing through, Lil." ...] "I'll buy you a drink if I have any money" she said. //// 'Had' is required by the conditional, not the temporal framework. 'She told me she would buy me a drink if she [then] had any money [by then].'

Comment: Thanks Edwin, much appreciated.